# How to determine if a line is tangent to a circle?

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

In my book the question is:

Prove that line: $x - 3y = 5$ is a tangent to the circle: $x^2 + y^2 - 6x + 8y + 15 = 0$

*P.S:* If there is any general proof or derivation of it please let me know.I am also infant in mathematics.Only has learnt Line, Trigonometry of 9th and 10th grade and learning circles write now.

Comment: Do you know how to get the vector $\vec {OA}$ where $O$ is the center of the circle and $A$ is the point of intersection of the line and the circle? After that do you how to get the directing vector of the line? These 2 vecors must be perpendicular if the line is a tangent to the circle (check this by using dot product)

Comment: Sorry sir, I haven'e study vector yet.

Comment: You could also find the circle's center and radius, and see if the distance from the center to the line equals the radius. But the method of substitution of one variable might be simpler.

Comment: Using pole-polar relationships, you could show either that the pole of this line lies on the circle or on the line, or that the line satisfies the dual conic equation to this circle’s. In any case, there are many ways to solve this problem but the appropriate one for you should use the material that’s already been presented in your book. Unfortunately, you haven’t given us any sense aside from the “analytic-geometry” tag of what you’re allowed to use in your proof.

Comment: Hmm... thinking more about my quibble with one of the answers, in order to give you a useful answer to your question we need to know how you define when a line is tangent to a circle.

Answer (score 4):

It has to touch the circle at one point, so plugging in x = 3y+5 in the second equation must have one solution for y.

You can also prove it by finding the line that passes through the point of intersection and the center of the circle, and then you can show that these two lines are prependicular to each other from the slopes.

Comment: And since it's a quadratic equation, one must have $\Delta=0$.

Comment: That is true if the line passes the circle at only one point, which is the definition of the tangent line of a circle.

Comment: Precisely. It's a way to check that the line is indeed a tangent.

Answer (score 0):

Using implicit differentiation, we can find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ for the circle.  Find the point of intersection for the line and the circle, and show that the slope of the tangent at that point is equal to the slope of the line.

\begin{align}
x^2+y^2-6x+8y+15 &=0 \\
\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^2+y^2-6x+8y+15) &=\dfrac{d}{dx}\ 0 \\
2x+2y\dfrac{dy}{dx}-6+8\dfrac{dy}{dx}& =0 \\
(2y+8)\dfrac{dy}{dx}&= 6-2x \\
\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=\dfrac{6-2x}{2y+8}=\dfrac{3-x}{y+4}
\end{align}

Plug in $x=3y+5$ into the circle.

\begin{align}
x^2+y^2-6x+8y+15 &=0 \\
(3y+5)^2+y^2-6(3y+5)+8y+15&=0 \\
9y^2+30y+25+y^2-18y-30+8y+15&=0 \\
10y^2+20y+10&=0 \\
y&=-1
\end{align}

Plug $y=-1$ into the line to get the point.
\begin{align}
x-3y &=5 \\
x-3(-1)&=5\\
x&=2 \Rightarrow  \textrm{point of intersection } (2,-1) \\
\end{align}

Slope of the tangent of the circle at $(2,-1)$:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{dy}{dx}\bigg|_{(2,-1)}&= \dfrac{3-(2)}{(-1)+4} =\dfrac{1}{3}\\
\end{align}

Slope of the given line:
\begin{align}
x-3y&=5\\
-3y&=-x+5\\
y&=\dfrac{1}{3}x+5\\
m&=\dfrac{1}{3}\\
\end{align}

Thus ends the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Every circle is tangent to a line if, by isolating a variable from the line function, and substituting the result you obtained with the same variable you obtained IN the line equation , you obtain a quadratic equation that has a null discriminant.
Or even better, you can  compute the distance of the center of the circle from the line and you'll have to find that this distance has the same value of the radius.

Regarding the latter, you have to verify that the center $(3,-4)$ is far from the line $\sqrt{10}$ (sorry, I have still to learn how to write in math format) by using the formula $d=\frac{\abs{ax
_C+by_C+c}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ with $ax+by+c=0$ as the equation of the line. The latter formula can used to compute a distance of a point $C$ from the line $ax+by+c=0$ in general.
Applying in your case, we get $$\frac{10}{\sqrt{10}}$$ which is $\sqrt{10}$ as expected.

Comment: you can take a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to improve the format of your answers in order to make them clearer. You could also attach images for the sake of explanation. It is better to have a nice answer rather than a fast one.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to examine the determinate of their joint quadratic equation.

Eliminate one variable, say, $x$, in the two equations to obtain,

$$y^2+2y+1=0$$

whose determinate is $\Delta = b^2-4ac = 0$. That is only one solution, meaning the two curves intersect at only one point and, therefore, tangential to each other.

Comment: I suggest phrasing your conclusion differently. Concluding from the fact that there’s only one intersection that the line is tangent to the circle relies on a particular property of conic-line intersections. It’s not true of two curves in general (it’s not even true of all conics unless you include intersections at infinity).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I was implicitly assume that one of them is a line (otherwise, the resulting equation would not be quadratic). Should have made it more clearer.